# How can I make a condition to evaluate that either two columns dont have null values in BIDS?

Tags: sql, ssis, bids

I am using Bussiness Intelligence Development Studio, and in the Conditional Split flow task, I want to make a condition for two columnss (state and city) that identifies if there is a null in values in any of them.

Comment: Basically, use the ISNULL function on the editor of your task. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2009/02/20/ssis-expression-language-and-the-conditional-split-transformation.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the conditional split component, create an output with the following condition :

```
ISNULL(state) || ISNULL(city)
```

All that have a state or city that is null will go into that output, and the rest will be in the default output.

Answer (score -1):

You can also add them then check.  Null + anything is null.

ISNULL(state + city)